# Days in Month solution

Tags: datetime, rust

The code, written in Rust, solves the [Days in Month problem](https://www.codechef.com/problems/NW1) in CodeChef. It is also one of my first few programs written in Rust.

The code is accepted so that there are no logical mistakes. I am more interested in getting review feedback on style. I am not particularly happy with the code as is; it is rather bulky.

```
use std::io;

fn read_line(stdin: &io::Stdin) -> io::Result<String>
{
    let mut input = String::new();
    match stdin.read_line(&mut input)
    {
        Ok(_) => Ok(input.trim().to_string()),
        Err(e) => Err(e)
    }
}

fn to_day_of_week(input: &str) -> Option<usize>
{
    if input == "mon"
    {
        Some(0)
    }
    else if input == "tues"
    {
        Some(1)
    }
    else if input == "wed"
    {
        Some(2)
    }
    else if input == "thurs"
    {
        Some(3)
    }
    else if input == "fri"
    {
        Some(4)
    }
    else if input == "sat"
    {
        Some(5)
    }
    else if input == "sun"
    {
        Some(6)
    }
    else
    { 
        None
    }
}

pub fn codechef_nw1()
{
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let read_first_line_result = read_line(&stdin);
    if read_first_line_result.is_ok()
    {
        let first_line = read_first_line_result.unwrap();
        let parse_first_line_result = first_line.parse::<i32>();
        if parse_first_line_result.is_ok()
        {
            let t = parse_first_line_result.unwrap();
            for _i in 0..t
            {
                let read_test_line_result = read_line(&stdin);
                if read_test_line_result.is_ok()
                {
                    let test_line = read_test_line_result.unwrap();
                    let find_space_result = test_line.find(' ');
                    if find_space_result.is_some()
                    {
                        let space_index = find_space_result.unwrap();
                        let test_token_1 = &test_line[..space_index];
                        let test_token_2 = &test_line[space_index + 1..];
                        let parse_day_result = test_token_1.parse::<i32>();
                        if parse_day_result.is_ok()
                        {
                            let days = parse_day_result.unwrap();
                            let day_of_week_result = to_day_of_week(test_token_2);
                            if day_of_week_result.is_some()
                            {
                                let mut day_of_week = day_of_week_result.unwrap();
                                let mut stats = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
                                for _d in 0..days
                                {
                                    stats[day_of_week] = stats[day_of_week] + 1;
                                    day_of_week = day_of_week + 1;
                                    day_of_week = day_of_week % 7;
                                }
                                println!("{} {} {} {} {} {} {}", stats[0], stats[1], stats[2], stats[3], stats[4], stats[5], stats[6]);
                            }                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`to_day_of_week` can be heavily simplified by using `match` instead of `if`-`else`:

```
fn to_day_of_week(input: &str) -> Option<usize> {
    match input {
        "mon" => Some(0),
        "tues" => Some(1),
        "wed" => Some(2),
        "thurs" => Some(3),
        "fri" => Some(4),
        "sat" => Some(5),
        "sun" => Some(6),
        _ => None,
    }
}
```

The bulkiness of your code can be somewhat helped if you provide additional functions and use `?` instead of `unwrap`. Using `unwrap` is discouraged, as far as I know. If you don't want to use `?` or additional functions, early returns prevent your code from getting too much indented.

Answer (score 3):

We are certainly a bit far from clear, idiomatic Rust here. Let's start from the top.

The match statement in `read_line` can be made generic over the source type. It just needs to implement `BufRead`. But spoiler alert: we won't need it!

```
fn read_line<T: BufRead>(mut src: T) -> io::Result<String> {
    let mut input = String::new();
    match src.read_line(&mut input) {
        Ok(_) => Ok(input.trim().to_string()),
        Err(e) => Err(e),
    }
}
```

In `to_day_of_week`, match statements do work with strings:

```
fn to_day_of_week(input: &str) -> Option<usize> {
    match input {
        "mon" => Some(0),
        "tues" => Some(1),
        "wed" => Some(2),
        "thurs" => Some(3),
        "fri" => Some(4),
        "sat" => Some(5),
        "sun" => Some(6),
        _ => None
    }
}
```

There is one thing more that can be considered here, although not very important: `usize` is a bit too broad for a day-of-the-week identifier. We can make it explicit that this function returns a day of the week by defining a new type:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
pub enum DayOfWeek {
    Monday = 0,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday,
    Sunday,
}
```

At this point we can also implement some utility functions and promote  `to_day_of_week` to a static method.

```
impl DayOfWeek {

    pub fn from_offset(offset: usize) -> Option<Self> {
        use DayOfWeek::*;
        match offset {
            0 => Some(Monday),
            1 => Some(Tuesday),
            // and so on ...
            _ => None,
        }
    }

    pub fn from_text(input: &str) -> Option<Self> {
        use DayOfWeek::*;
        match input {
            "mon" => Some(Monday),
            "tues" => Some(Tuesday),
            // and so on ...
            _ => None,
        }
    }

    /// get the next day of the week
    pub fn next(self) -> Self {
        DayOfWeek::from_offset((self as usize + 1) % 7).unwrap()
    }
}
```

The current error handling code is very verbose and not very useful. Basically, you are silently skipping the following steps if any of the functions fail. Rather than `if` followed by `unwrap`, this would be more idiomatically achieved with pattern matching:

```
match read_line(x) {
    Ok(v) => {/* do things */}
    _ => {/* ignore */}
}
```

... which should also ring an alarm bell at this point. We are ignoring these errors completely, including I/O errors! Rust provides cleaner ways to escape from recoverable results, such as [the `?` operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#a-shortcut-for-propagating-errors-). Let's first choose to enclose the code found in `codechef_nw1` into a new function returning a `Result` (in this case a dynamic error type `Box<Error>` is fine). Then, we can replace all places where `Result`s emerge with a `?`. This should clear a lot of boilerplate. The first few lines would look something like this:

```
pub fn run_codechef_nw1() -> Result<(), Box<::std::error::Error>> {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let t = read_line(&stdin)?.parse::<i32>()?;
    for _ in 0..t {
// ...
```

When fetching the day of the week and the day in the month, splitting the two components from the string can be done with `split`. I chose to `unwrap` both tokens out of the `Option`, but in the event that your function needs to be robust against malformed input, you should conditionally return a custom error instead.

```
let mut tokens = test_line.split(' ');
let test_token_1 = tokens.next().unwrap();
let test_token_2 = tokens.next().unwrap();
```

Considering the new `DayOfWeek` type, we should now have:

```
let mut day_of_week = DayOfWeek::from_text(test_token_2).unwrap();
```

Array initialization can also be shortened with a different syntax:

```
let mut stats = [0; 7];
```

For the counting loop, we can do two things: (1) convert `day_of_week` to a `usize` with the `as` operator; (2) use the `+=` operator for incrementing `stats` elements:

```
for _ in 0..days {
    stats[day_of_week as usize] += 1;
    day_of_week = day_of_week.next();
}
```

At the end of your function, don't forget

```
    Ok(())
}
```

The main entry function may then do something like this:

```
run_codechef_nw1().unwrap();
```

We can also make our `run_codechef_nw1` functions generic over any source of data by making it take some type which implements `BufRead`.

```
pub fn codechef_nw1<T: BufRead>(mut stdin: T) -> Result<(), Box<::std::error::Error>> {
    let t = read_line(&mut stdin)?.parse::<i32>()?;
// ...
```

Note that the input source needs to be passed by mutable reference to other functions, since we don't want it to be moved after the first read. With this done, we can even hardcode our own test inputs.

```
fn main() {
    // fake input data
    let input_data = br#"2
28 mon
31 wed"#;

    let stdin = Cursor::new(input_data);
    run_codechef_nw1(stdin).unwrap();
}
```

#### Using iterators

Rather than `read_line`, working with an iterator of lines will often lead to nicer code. With a small little twist at the beginning of the function, we can fetch and handle incoming lines with the iterator API:

```
let mut lines = stdin.lines();
let t = lines.next().unwrap()?.parse::<i32>()?;
for line in lines.take(t) { // consider the first `t` lines only
    let test_line = line?; // handle line reading error
// ...
```

As usual in Rust, don't forget to call `rustfmt` over your code to keep it formatted according to community conventions.

Here's the [full solution in the Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e98839ea17a954ccc7e29702c8d36513&version=stable).

Comment: Enum variants would commonly use `PascalCase` instead of `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE`. You could also consider implementing [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html) instead of the bespoke `from_text`. If you really wanted to be cutting-edge, you could use [`TryFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html) instead of `from_offset`. It's micro-optimization, but I'd probably use a `u8` instead of a `usize`. I'm [not a fan of using the discriminant to allow rotating through the values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38030382/155423), but it works.

Comment: @Shepmaster I propose we call it `STEPPED_ON_SNAKE_CASE`.